# How to get the payload(in json format) coming under network tab of the browser to the springboot controller?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My frontend team has implemented the frontend of the application where they are using javascript, html and css. They have different fields on their HTML from which consist of numerous parameters.

Like **Your Name*: filled by user*
The box which is accepting **Type of Action** , **Suggestion Text** and **Suggestion Postback**. Also they have **+** button where they can add one more same box. In the *Type Of Action* user can select upto three things called **Reply**, **User action** and **Dialer Action**

Below is the Image what I am trying to elaborate:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now when User is hitting submit I can see the the payload under network tab of browser is getting generated and it consist of the values which get passed

```
txtName: 
text: ff
Postback: fgdgd
url: 
phone-no: 
text: dsd
Postback: gffg
url: gdg
phone-no: 
text: dggd
Postback: gd
url: 
phone-no: 4334
```

As I am the Springboot guy and I have started working on it too very recently, is their any way I can take complete payload in my sprinboot controller as it is and from there I can manipulate it as I wanted. Basically I wanted this complete payload in my sprinboot controller as it is, after user submits.

Below is the code given to me by the frontend guys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <style>body{
    margin: 0;
}
.contact-form{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 70%;
}
.contact-form h3{
    text-align: center;
    color: #0062cc;
}
.main-input input.form-control {
    margin: 15px 0%;
}
.add-btn{
    text-align: end;
}
.act_btn{
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 10px;

}
.suggestion-box {
    margin: 15px 0%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #d9d9d973;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #80808063;
    align-items: self-end;
}
.inner-select{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px 12px;
}
.url,.phone-no{
    display: none;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div>
    <div class="container contact-form">
        <form method="post" action="@{/templates/save}">
            <h3>Test Form</h3>

            <div class="row main-input">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="txtName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" value=""/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value=""/>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-btn">
                <button class="btn act_btn add"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="main-select">
                <div class="suggestion-box">
                    <div class="inner-select">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Type of Action</label>
                            <select id="select_type" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option value="1">Reply</option>
                                <option value="2">URL Action</option>
                                <option value="3">Dialer Action</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner-select">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Suggestion Text</label>
                            <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner-select">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Suggestion Postback</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Postback" class="form-control" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner-select url">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">URL/URI to open</label>
                            <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inner-select phone-no">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Phone Number to Dial</label>
                            <input type="number" name="phone-no" class="form-control" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn act_btn remove" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var rowHtml = '<div class="suggestion-box"><div class="inner-select"><div class="form-group"><label class="form-label">Type of Action</label> <select id="select_type" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"><option value="1">Reply</option> <option value="2">URL Action</option> <option value="3">Dialer Action</option></select></div></div><div class="inner-select"><div class="form-group"><label class="form-label">Suggestion Text</label><input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" value=""/></div> </div><div class="inner-select"><div class="form-group"><label class="form-label">Suggestion Postback</label><input type="text" name="Postback" class="form-control" value=""/> </div> </div><div class="inner-select url"> <div class="form-group"><label class="form-label">URL/URI to open</label><input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" value=""/></div></div><div class="inner-select phone-no"><div class="form-group"><label class="form-label">Phone Number to Dial</label><input type="number" name="phone-no" class="form-control" value=""/></div></div><button class="btn act_btn remove" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button></div>';

        $(".add-btn button").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //addRow();
        });



            function addRow() {
                $('.main-select').append(rowHtml);
            }

            function removeRow(button) {
              button.closest(".suggestion-box").remove();
            }

            $('.main-select .suggestion-box:first-child').find('.remove').hide();


            $(".add-btn button").on('click', function () {
              addRow();
              if($(".main-select .suggestion-box").length > 1) {
                //alert("Can't remove row.");
                $(".remove").show();
              }
            });
            $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
              if($(".main-select .suggestion-box").size() == 1) {
                $(".remove").hide();
              } else {
                removeRow($(this));

                if($(".main-select .suggestion-box").size() == 1) {
                    $(".remove").hide();
                }

              }
            });


            $(document).on('change','.inner-select select',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var dropVal = $(this).val();

            if(dropVal == 1){
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".url").hide();
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".phone-no").hide();
            }
            if(dropVal == 2){
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".url").show();
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".phone-no").hide();
            }
            if(dropVal == 3){
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".url").hide();
                $(this).parents('.suggestion-box').children(".phone-no").show();
            }
        });


    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And My controller code is something where I tried capturing it numerous times but it is not working, Below is my springboot funtion where I basically wanted that payload to be captured.

```
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveData(@ModelAttribute("template") TemplateData template,
                           @RequestParam("textInputs") List<String> textInputs,
                           @RequestParam("postbackInputs") List<String> postbackInputs,
                           @RequestParam("text") String text) {
        // Construct the complete JSON structure using user input
        StringBuilder jsonDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        jsonDataBuilder.append("{\"suggestions\": [");
        for (int i = 0; i < textInputs.size(); i++) {
            String jsonData = "{\"reply\": {" +
                    "\"text\": \"" + textInputs.get(i) + "\"," +
                    "\"postbackData\": \"" + postbackInputs.get(i) + "\"" +
                    "}}";
            jsonDataBuilder.append(jsonData);
            if (i < textInputs.size() - 1) {
                jsonDataBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        jsonDataBuilder.append("], \"text\": \"").append(text).append("\"}");
        // Set timestamp
        template.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        // Save the complete JSON data to the database
        template.setJsonData(jsonDataBuilder.toString());

        templateService.saveData(template);

        return "redirect:/templates/list";

        //return "redirect:/success"; // Redirect to a success page
    }
```

help and comments would be really appreciable, As I am in the learning process soon I willa ble to pick it up and try to help community too.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwPst.png